# WPF MVVM guidance for beginner

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, mvvm

Trying to make a document viewer, like Acrobat, which consists of pages, and each page consists of thumbnail images (of varying sizes at users discretion). I’m not sure how to design the MVVM.
At the moment I have:

**DocumentViewModel**, **PageViewModel**, **ThumbnailViewModel**

> DocumentViewModel has ObservableCollection()  // keeps track of Pages
>
> PageViewModel has ObservableCollection() // keeps track of thumbnails to be displayed by document.

However this design causes problems. For example, if there are 3 pages of thumbnails. And half of the thumbnails are removed from page 2, then page 3 thumbnails should automatically relocate to the newly available space on page 2. Each PageViewModel would have to have awareness about each other, which would be breaking the MVVM policies, no? Would it be better to have the 2 ObservableCollections, declared within DocumentViewModel?

Any help, pointers, advice, guidance welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! i'm using both helgeheldre's suggestion of using the DocumentViewModel as the controller and Jen H's suggestion of using Caliburn.Micro's Framework for messaging.

All messages get routed to the DocumentViewModel (Via EventAgregator), who then delegates tasks to individual PageViewModels.

Answer (score 1):

The ViewModels do not need to be aware of each other.

I suggest using any MVVM framework of your choice, for example [Caliburn Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/). CM allows you to send **messages** between objects without them knowing each other and keep them completely **decoupled**.

Simply put, the Caliburn Micro framework offers an `EventAgregator` to dispatch the messages. The objects that need to send a message register the message type with the `EventAggregator` and the objects that need to receive subscribe for them also at the `EventAggregator`.

See an example of this here:[Introduction to messaging with Caliburn.Micro’s EventAggregator](http://joshearl.wordpress.com/2011/03/31/introduction-to-messaging-with-caliburn-micros-eventaggregator/).

Comment: thanks for the tip, I haven't used a MVVM framework yet, I'm reading over your link now

Answer (score 1):

The PageViewModels should not be aware of each-other.

DocumentViewModel will be aware of the PageViewModels you have and it can handle redeistribution of ThumbnailViewModels. Let the DocumentViewModel handle number of pages and ThumbNailViewModels per PageViewModel.

If you move the ObservableCollection of Thumbnails out to the DocumentViewModel you can dynamically create your PageViewModels based on need. Whenever the ThumbnailViewModel collection changes you will get notifications and you can then alter the PageViewModels based on that.

Comment: Regarding your last sentence, who would handle redistribution? PageViewModels? Wouldn't that give need to awareness of each other? Or would DocumentViewModel handle redistribution?

Comment: My thought was to give that responsibility to the DocumentViewModel, Since it will be responsible of creating the PageViewModels i find it natural that it will distribute the ThumbnailViewModels among them